# Rename with bat file from an specific number

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have a bat file that rename all of the png files to data_ files. It starts from `data_1` and `data_2` .... I want to start with `data_140` and `data_141`...

How to do that?

```
:: Renaming files
for %%a in (*.png) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "fname=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ren "!fname!" data_!count!.png
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: What's the problem? 'Just preset your `count`variable before the `for`.

Comment: You don't need to preset your `count` variable.  From `help set`:  "If an environment variable name is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value of zero is used [with the `/A` switch]."

Comment: @indiv: I meant preset it with `set count=139`. Sorry, I thought, that was obvious.

Comment: @Stephan:  Oh, it turns out I didn't actually read the question.  I see now.

Comment: @indiv - Yes, it is true SET /A treats an undefined variable as 0. But it is not a good idea to assume the variable is not already defined. Better to always explicitly define your starting value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. `SET /A count+=1` starts with count=0 as it's not defined yet. If you want your script to start at 140 just do `set count=139` before you enter the loop:

```
:: Renaming files
set count = 139
for %%a in (*.png) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "fname=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ren "!fname!" data_!count!.png
    endlocal
)
```